# mysqld is not producing binary log

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm trying to understand why `mysqld` is not writing binary log anymore...

```
[root@ip-10-179-155-214 mysql]# grep ^log-bin /etc/my.cnf
log-bin=mysql-bin
[root@ip-10-179-155-214 mysql]# ll mysql-bin.*
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    28463 Jun 27 16:04 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  1038814 Jun 27 16:04 mysql-bin.000002
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql      264 Jun 27 16:06 mysql-bin.000003
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql      264 Jun 29 10:22 mysql-bin.000004
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 23751127 Jun 29 10:30 mysql-bin.000005
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql      264 Jun 29 10:35 mysql-bin.000006
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 23755331 Jun 29 10:45 mysql-bin.000007
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql      245 Jun 29 10:45 mysql-bin.000008
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql      152 Jun 29 10:45 mysql-bin.index
[root@ip-10-179-155-214 mysql]# date
Thu Jul  3 17:55:13 EDT 2014
[root@ip-10-179-155-214 mysql]# ps auxww | grep mysqld
mysql     4131  0.0  0.0 115348  1688 ?        Ss   Jun29   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
mysql     4787  0.1  8.9 3822688 331928 ?      Sl   Jun29  10:13 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/ip-10-179-155-214.ec2.internal.err --open-files-limit=8192 --pid-file=ip-10-179-155-214.ec2.internal.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
root     18996  0.0  0.0 112640   976 pts/2    S+   17:56   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
[root@ip-10-179-155-214 mysql]#
```

any ideas what am I missing?

*** UPDATE ***

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@global.sql_log_bin;
+----------------------+
| @@global.sql_log_bin |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000008 |      245 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select NOW() - interval variable_value second from information_schema.global_status where variable_name='uptime';
+----------------------------------------+
| NOW() - interval variable_value second |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2014-06-29 10:45:14.000000             |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Please run this query `select @@global.sql_log_bin;`. What is the answer, 0 or 1 ??? Please run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` and tell the output.

Comment: Please run this `select NOW() - interval variable_value second from information_schema.global_status where variable_name='uptime';` and tell me the output. This will be the time mysql last started.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I updated my question with output from your queries, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Things I'd check:

- Are any changes happening? Binary log doesn't include SELECT queries, only changes. Compare the timestamp on files like ib_logfile*.
- Are [replication filters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rules.html) excluding changes being made?
- Are sessions making changes while `SQL_LOG_BIN=0` is suppressing binary logging, either globally as @RolandoMySQLDBA suggests, or else per session?
- Disk is full?
- You are looking at binlogs in the wrong directory?

Comment: `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0, so I assume replication itself is working fine, disk is not full and i'm looking at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your comment

> Seconds_Behind_Master is 0, so I assume replication itself is working fine, disk is not full and i'm looking at the right place

The problem is simple

- You have setup MySQL Replication
- The Slave has been running since `2014-06-29 10:45:14`

  - `mysql-bin.000007` has the same datetime
  - `mysql-bin.000008` has the same datetime
  - `mysql-bin.index` has the same datetime
- Seconds_Behind_Master is 0, so replication is running fine.

Why are changes made on the the Slave not making it to its binary logs ?

You forgot to add [**log-slave-updates**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) to `my.cnf` on the Slave.

I have written about this before : [Multi-master + slaves replication in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60391/multi-master-slaves-replication-in-mysql/60434#60434)

Simply add [**log-slave-updates**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) to `my.cnf`, restart mysql, and everything will be fine.

## Give it a Try !!!